# How to pass Context.User.Identity.GetUserName to Select Statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, ado.net

I am creating a ASP.NET web form in Visual Studio 2013 to update Customer Information in the Customer database table. I have created a SQLDataSource with a username (from UserAccounts table) field.  When building the data source in VS2013 I am trying build a custom SELECT statement and make sure the username = Context.UserIdentity.GetUserName().

Every time I try to execute the query using the query builder, it returns null. Here is what I tried to do:

```
SELECT Username FROM UserAccounts WHERE (Username = @Username ) AND (@Username = @Username + 'Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()')
```

I am trying to concatenate the current user to the user name field so that when the Update Registration link is clicked, the correct username populate.
Not sure what I am doing here.

Essentially what I have to do is "build a string" around the method (GetUserName) in the where clause of the select statement.

Comment: You're not showing how you're building/using the database query in the code.  If you're using ADO.NET to execute a query then you're going to need to add a query parameter and use the identity value in that parameter.  *Do not* directly concatenate the username directly into the query, that's a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: I am trying to configure the SQLDataSource within the ASP.Net web form's designer,  After creating the Connection String, it gives you the option to create a custom SQL Statement,  And that's where I typed the code above.  There is a query builder button that you can use to execute the query but it returns a null value

Comment: Inexperience (e.g. public disclosure of a SQL vulnerability) is not a good reason for a downvote IMO. We were all dummies.

Comment: Would something like:                                                                          SELECT Username FROM UserAccounts WHERE (Username = @Username) AND (@Username = 'Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()')

Comment: @user2958278 - @Username is a SQL parameter. You must specify a value in your code, or else it won't have a value (will be null) when the query executes. This will look *something* like `dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Username", Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()));` Otherwise, `WHERE (Username = @Username)` won't match any records.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy where would I specify this? In the aspx file?

Comment: @user2958278 wherever the C# code for your page is. This is normally an .aspx.cs file that is linked to the .aspx file.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy it says there is no definiton for GetUserName() and I have to define it like: DbCommand test; test.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()));